# Definition of ''Rank a group''

Tags: group-theory, definition

Let $G$ a group.

I want compare this definitions:

$1)$  I define $rk(G)=\min\{\lvert X\rvert: X\subseteq G, G=\langle X\rangle\}$

$2)$ (Prüfer rank) Suppose G $\underline{abelian}$ and i define $rg(G)=r_0(G)+\sup\limits_{p\in\mathbb{P}} r_p(G)$ where $r_0(G)$ is the torsion-free rank  and $r_p(G)$ is the $p$ rank

$3)$  If exists $r\in\mathbb{N}$  such that any finitely-generated subgroup of $G$ has a system of generators of at most $r$ elements, then I define $r(G)$ as the minimal number $r$ with this property. Otherwise i define $r(G)=\infty$.

---

If $G$ is fintely generated then $rk(G)\le r(G)$.
I ask a example (if exist) of finitely generated group (eventually abelian) with finite rank $r(G)$ and $rk(G)<r(G)$.
Note that if $G$ is abelian with $r(G)<\infty$ then $r(G)=rg(G)$.

If $G$ is abelian how i in general compare $rk(G)$ and $rg(G)$? Are they equal or there is an inequality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $G$ is finitely generated and abelian, then the $p$-rank is the number of cyclic factors in the $p$-part of the decomposition. If I'm not mistaken, the Prufer rank is the number of cyclic summands in the invariant factor decomposition.